# CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config. While using S3 SDK in EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Architecture of my application have one elastic load-balancer and auto scaling group, In Auto Scaling Group I have created Launch configuration to instantiate EC2 instances with UserData to run nodejs server on each instance. 
**AWS_ACCESS_ID** and **AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY** has been added in EC2 environment variables using User Data. So, in my server-side(Node) code I am not giving these credentials.
It is giving error when I use S3 SDK.
Error says: "**CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config**".

---

But, if I use the same User Data to create individual EC2 Instance without any load-balancer and Auto Scaling Group, It works fine.

And also, if I stop the node server manually (when I have the load-balancer and auto scaling group) on EC2 instance and run it again, it starts working fine.

Following is the user data I have for EC2 Launch Configuration.

I am using Amazon-Linux on EC2.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e -x
echo AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=********** >> /etc/environment
echo AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=****************************** >> /etc/environment
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash -
sudo yum install -y git nodejs
git clone https://github.com/Vaaceph/BackEndCloud.git && cd BackEndCloud
sudo npm install
DEBUG=express:* node server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for EC2 is to assign an instance profile as per: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/us-iam-role.html

This has benefit that the credentials used by EC2 are short lived, automatically rotated and don't require ongoing management of the user access key/secret key.